# How to check if a variable exists in a file for Sadscripting

Tags: variables, if-statement, vb6

A buddy and I are at a roadblock on a little project. We're trying to check if a variable exists in a file, and if it doesn't, write it to the file.

Now we already know that

```
Call PutVar("accounts\extra\" & GetPlayerLogin(index) & ".ini", "VARIABLES", "test", CInt(0))
```

Will write to the file:

> \accounts\extra\username.ini
>
> [VARIABLES]
>
> test=0

However, what were trying to figure out is if the variable already exists in the file accounts\extra\username.ini then not to write it, an example would be something like:

```
If GetVar("accounts\extra\" & GetPlayerLogin(index) & ".ini", "VARIABLES", "test") = Doesn't Exist Then
   Call PutVar("accounts\extra\" & GetPlayerLogin(index) & ".ini", "VARIABLES", "test", CInt(0))
 Else
   Call PlayerMSG(Index, "It already exists!", C_WHITE) 
End If
```

However "Exists" isn't a recognized term, its more or less just english. If anyone has any advice on something to at least *try* to get it working, I'd appreciate it alot.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this VB6, or Sadscript? You have it tagged as both, but there isn't a built-in "GetVar" in VB6 that I know of.

Comment: Have you confirmed that PutVar does indeed write a duplicate value?  Perhaps PutVar has built-in logic to check for an already existing value and replaces it, which would make sense since there would likely be times that you would want to change the values of existing keys.  There should likely also be a corresponding DelVar or some variant that deletes key entries.